# How to chain a webclient call on each items from a list from the first call

Tags: spring, webclient, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two objects

```
CarParts {
    String   id
    WorkItem workItem
}

WorkItemResponse {
    List<WorkItem> resource; <- always contains one item.
}
```

I want to make a webclient on the car-parts which would return me a `Mono<List<CarParts>>` for each item in the list i want to use the id on the second call and then set `Carparts`'s each `WorkItem` object with the result of the 2nd call

I also want to do a

```
Mono<List<Carparts>> carpartsmono = webclient.get.exchange();

Mono<WorkItemResponse> itemResponse = webclient.get().uri( item.id of carparts)

carpartsMono.flatmap(item -> item.stream().map(t -> t.setWorkItem(webclient.get("uri + 
     t.getId)).block().getResource().get(0)).collect(Collectors.AsList));
```

but I not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reactive stack, one should try to make all code async, in your case one of the way is shown below :

```
Flux<CarPart> carPartFlux=
    webClient.get()
    .uri("/car-parts/{id}")
    .exchange()
    .bodyToFlux(CarParts.class)
    .map(carPart ->  {
        return
        webclient.get()
                 .uri("/workitems/" + cartPart.getWorkItemId())
                 .exchange()
                 .bodyToMono(WorkItemResponse.class)
                 .map(workitem ->  {
                      carPart.setWorkItem(workitem);
                      return carPart;
                 });
                 
    });
```

Now you can pass Mono of car part. Please try to avoid .block call as long as possible. Like if you are sending this to rest api client, you directly pass carPartMono in rest api response.

Also above code is sample and it can be improved further which depends on current execution conditions. Like can caching help. So you can start with this and monitor performance and take next steps.

Comment: .exchange()
    .bodyToMono(CarParts.class) < returns Mono<List<CarPart>> <--- the map function after it can't be applied since its a mono. do i have to flatmap(items -> items.stream.map(item ->)?

Comment: Oh if input is list then you can use bodyToFlux to convert List to string and then map each. I have update answer the above.